# How to append a series of clicked elements to textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of elements which when I click I want to insert its html into a textarea.

If I do this I get a lot of the elements not just the checked one:

```
jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function () {
    var urls = [];
    jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
    });
    var str = '';
    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        str += '<div class="item"><img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + url + '"></div>';
    });
    jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, val){
        return val + str; 
    });
});
```

If I do this i get no text at all into the textarea:

```
jQuery('#usp-custom-4').append(str);
```

And if I do this works fine:

```
jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(str);
```

But the issue with the last one is that I have 2 different functions with 2 different set of elements and when I click on the first set it is fine but if I click on the second set it removes the value I inserted by selecting the first set and it inserts only the second. Both sets must insert their selected html into the same textarea `<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>`

A sample [jsFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/ya7uefet/1/), on here it adds but when I uncheck it doesn't remove.

**UPDATE**

global array `var urls = [];`

Function1:

```
  function (data) {
    jQuery.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
      var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
      var $items = jQuery('<div class="item">'.concat(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="', uniq, '" value="valuable" id="', uniq, '" />',
        '<label for="', uniq, '">',
          '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '">',
        '</label>',
    '</div>'));
      jQuery(".masonry").append($items);
      jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox', function () {
        jQuery('.masonry .item :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
          urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
        });
        var str = '';
        urls.forEach(function (url) {
          str += '<div class="item"><img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + url + '"></div>';
        });
        jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(str); 
      });
    });
  });
```

Function2

```
function (data) {
        jQuery.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
          var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
          var $items = jQuery('<div class="item">'.concat(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="', uniq, '" value="valuable" id="', uniq, '" />',
            '<label for="', uniq, '">',
              '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '">',
            '</label>',
        '</div>'));
          jQuery(".masonryB").append($items);
          jQuery('body').on('change', '.masonryB :checkbox', function () {
            jQuery('.masonryB :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
              urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
            });
            console.log(urls)
            var str = '';
            urls.forEach(function (url) {
              str += '<div class="item"><img onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + url + '"></div>';
            });
            jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(str); 
          });
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a testable example

Comment: If you want only the item was was added to be removed from textarea and leave the rest in there, that would require a lot more work because the code needs to find out what was added by that checkbox that got unchecked and remove just that string from the textarea.

Comment: @alfredo I am pushing into an array what has been clicked already. I believe what i will have to do is join the 2 arrays since I have to function pushing to 2 different arrays and then adding

Comment: Why have different listeners for doing basically the same thing? Why not [do something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ya7uefet/3/) and listen to all changes and update the textarea on every change?

Comment: @E.Sundin because I have 2 buttons to load images with 2 different functions

Comment: I stand corrected. @E.Sundin did it!

Comment: @E.Sundin that won't work, I already have a working example like you did as I stated in the question but see when you do `.on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox` when I load the second set it will have to address a different container with images so `.on('change', '.masonryB .item :checkbox`

Comment: @alfredo I already had what E.Sundin did, but that isn't a solution as it will only work for one set

Comment: @RobertoMarras Then just add that as a selector too? `.on('change', '.masonry .item :checkbox, .masonryB .item :checkbox')`

Comment: but that second click event is within a second function

Comment: @E.Sundin and also that click event it is called when ajax data return so it will be out of scope

Comment: It seems to me you have not provided a fully testable example. I'm having trouble following what you really want.

Comment: @E.Sundin I have put the array outside the functions to make it global and then i am adding to that but it is adding lots of them not only the clicked one but I believe this is the correct road

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake in your code:

```
jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, val){
    return val + str; 
});
```

Should become

```
jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, val){
    return str; 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/digelim/w9vbtw8q/

Comment: Ok true but I do get to the same point as if I was only doing `jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(str); ` the thing is that when I launch the second function and I click on an image, the textarea removes the previous function added images

Comment: I am wondering if I should be setting this as global outside all functions `str = '';`

Comment: just tried and when I click on an image instead of adding just one, it adds many repeated ones

Comment: i give up, I will simply add a new textarea where to push the second set..

Comment: I think got your point. The thing is that every time you loop over the images you will get a reordered list. If you want to keep the previous order you would need to use a different logic in your code...

Comment: Yeah i couldn't manage to make it with what I had but I can't just write it again as I'm too busy, simply resolved it by adding a second textarea where to save the second set. I will leave the question open in case anyone will write the new logic or find a different solution with what posted on here. Thanks a lot hot